# Python lxml xpath not working

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Below is a simple program to print the names of the professors in the link       : http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/index.php?secret=d2RkOUgybWlNZzJwQXdLc28wNzh6UT09

The xpath query `//font[1]/b/a/b/text()` gives the output names when tested seperately. However this program gives an empty list as output. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import sys
import requests
import lxml.html

def getdata():
    v = lxml.html.document_fromstring(requests.get("http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/index.php?secret=d2RkOUgybWlNZzJwQXdLc28wNzh6UT09").content)
    profs = v.xpath('//font[1]/b/a/b/text()')
    for prof in profs:
        print prof

if __name__=="__main__":
    getdata()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page uses AJAX to render, i.e.: the list of elements you need is loaded via JavaScript.

This is the URL where the data is actually served:

http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/faculty4.php?_=1451158710268

I found it by using the developer tools in Chromium, looking for XHR requests.

Comment: Works like a charm..Thanks!
How did you come up with the URL?